# Failed to upload 1GB video on server from ios App

Tags: nsdata

I am working on an app in which I need to upload larger video file like 500 MB to 1 GB or more than 1GB. I am uploading video using ASIFormDataRequest. It takes too much time for uploading. please help me out.

```
ASIFormDataRequest *videoUploadRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
        //[videoUploadRequest setPostFormat:ASIMultipartFormDataPostFormat];
        NSLog(@"%@",objProductInfo1.videoData);
        [videoUploadRequest setData:objProductInfo1.videoData withFileName:@"sample.mp4" andContentType:@"video/quicktime" forKey:@"video_file"];
        videoUploadRequest.requestMethod = @"POST";
        //[videoUploadRequest setData:videoData forKey:@"video_file"];
        // [videoUploadRequest addRequestHeader:@"content-type" value:@"multipart/form-data"];
        [videoUploadRequest setTimeOutSeconds:60000000]; // try using time out for your post...
        videoUploadRequest.allowCompressedResponse = NO;
        videoUploadRequest.useCookiePersistence = NO;
        videoUploadRequest.shouldCompressRequestBody = NO;
        [videoUploadRequest setDelegate:self];
        [videoUploadRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(VideoStartUpload:)];
        [videoUploadRequest startAsynchronous];
```